# How can I add/import the ChibiOS library for an embedded project in Visual&nbsp;Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, header-files, .a, chibios

I want to use the *ch.h* file from [ChibiOS](https://github.com/ChibiOS/ChibiOS) in my project. The embedded project is created and is using HAL drivers for [STM32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STM32). I want to find a way to add or import the ChibiOS library to the current project.

My question is that

1. how can I add these embedded libraries with lots of dependencies by [VisualGDB](https://visualgdb.com/) in Visual Studio?
2. Do I need to create .lib files of ChibiOS/RT?
3. What are the differences between C/C++ paths and linker paths?
4. Is adding .a and .h files enough or do I have to look for other files?

There are three ways that I followed and it wasn't successful.

1. I followed [the link](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a2-using-libraries-with-visual-studio-2005-express) to add the paths.
   The files that added to projects are *libch.a* and *ch.h*. It is called other header files inside *ch.h*. Then, I added the other header paths to C/C++ "additional include directories" too. After I added the third header file, I got the error "redefinition".
2. The second way, I wanted to use [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg), a library manager. But the ChibiOS/RT library wasn't available in [vcpkg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vcpkg).
3. One other way is to add libraries in standard libraries without adding any paths. But how can I find standard libraries? If the location is in the compiler (*gcc-arm-none-eabi*), the ChibiOS package was added, but it still wasn't detected in Visual Studio.

I really appreciate it if you know any tutorials or ways to add ChibiOS/RT in Visual Studio.

Comment: @drescherjm Yes. I am using visual studio professional 2017 + visualgdb.

Comment: I asked because so many people are using VSCode and still mention Visual Studio which is very different. I changed the tag to clarify the vs version.

Comment: Maybe did not unzip the file?  **no such file/directory** Can you find the required file in the path folder? It will be better to  provide detailed steps(how and where).

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT I solved the "no such file/directory" error by adding the paths. It is unzipped. I can also open and use the chibios libraries by chibiStudio without errors. I only don't know how to import it in visual studio. Because it is embedded, there are lots of dependencies (each header files call another header files from another path). I think it doesn't make sense to add each header path one by one. Or I don't know the way. The only steps I did, it is based on the shared [link](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a2-using-libraries-with-visual-studio-2005-express/)